# Ubuntu server installation on Ubuntu deskop

Tags: 12.04, server, software-installation, files

Will the installation of Ubuntu server on a Ubuntu desktop deletes the existing files and documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you do it.
If you hold your data on a separate partition (and dont format /erase this partition) then your data will survive.
If you have a single partition with Ubuntu desktop and your data on it, you could create a new partition for Ubuntu server.

There are lots of different ways of installing Ubuntu (and a lot depends on what you are trying to do), personally create partitions as follows:

1. BIOS / GRUB
2. First operating system (say Ubuntu desktop)
3. Second operating system (Say Ubuntu server)
4. swap

Comment: I have minimum files which are necessary. For that i will be backing them in a pen drive. The thing is during installation it asks for partition. The existing partition in the system is `/dev/sda1`. Should i select the same partition during installation? I do not want desktop edition and neither the old files.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes. If you install of sda1, and select "format" it will delete whatever you have installed on sda1 (I assume your exiting desktop install) along with any data on the partition. Make sure that your backup is good!